# Disjoint set as greedy solution

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, greedy, disjoint-sets

For scheduling jobs with given deadlines and profits on prompt completion,a greedy algorithm is suggested to maximize profits from all feasible sets of task.

However,the programmatic implementation recommended is disjoint set forests.

I have not been able to find any literature which demonstrates this implementation(easy enough for a non computer science/mathematical background).

Any reference to such a programming language agnostic implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Disjoint-set_forests

Comment: Amit links to some language agnostic code. Here are some actual implantations: - Python: https://github.com/simonemainardi/unionfind - C#: http://www.mathblog.dk/disjoint-set-data-structure/

Comment: I am aware of disjoint sets.I seek help in understanding how disjoint set forest would solve the problem above.Even pseudocode should should suffice